# java mockito matcher InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am using java spring boot and trying to write a mock for AWS s3 bucket in my unittest. Following is a code that cause some issue in when i execute the test

```
    @Mock 
    AmazonS3 s3client;

    when(s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(Mockito.any(String.class),
                    and(Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.endsWith(".txt"))
                ))).thenReturn(RawText);

            when(s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(Mockito.any(String.class),
                    and(Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.endsWith(".png"))
                ))).thenReturn(RawImage);
```

What i am trying to do is, I need to read png file and a text file from S3 bucket. based on the content type i am trying to return the object. When i execute the test i am getting

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
```

Note `RawImage` and `RawText` are the `S3Object` i created.  Can you help me in this  and what went wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you show your static imports?

Comment: import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.and;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;   @ernest_k- those are the imports i have

Answer (score 1):

Matchers are expected to be used as arguments to `getObject` in this case. So you may want to implement a custom matcher if your actual argument isn't a mock:

```
org.hamcrest.Matcher<GetObjectRequest> objectRequestMatcher = 
         new BaseMatcher<GetObjectRequest>() {

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object arg0) {
        return ((GetObjectRequest) arg0).getName().endsWith("txt"); //just an example
    }
};
```

And then:

```
when(s3client.getObject(org.mockito.Matchers.argThat(objectRequestMatcher)))
    .thenReturn(RawText);
```

Comment: Thank  you for your reply. I am finding difficulty in using the proper import statement. Should i use the hamcrest or mockito ? Can you please help me this ?

Comment: @Backtrack Sorry, I didn't test that in an IDE, and had the arguments wrong. Added full class names and corrected argument places.

Comment: @Backtrack Could be that we're using different versions... for me, `org.mockito.Matchers.argThat()` only takes a `org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>` as argument (`mockito-all-1.10.19`). What version are you using?.

Comment: @Backtrack Couldn't reproduce even after downgrading to your version. But your error message says `in the type ArgumentMatchers...`, but I used `org.mockito.Matchers.argThat(objectRequestMatcher)`, not `ArgumentMatchers.argThat`. Can you check that?

Comment: You probably have some conflicts. Can you try with just mockito-all?

Comment: yes - working. But since i am using the Sprint boot the auto wire is not happening. i am using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class). and getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.createStrict(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/internal/runners/InternalRunner;
 at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.<init>(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:154)